# How To Install Kubernetes Cluster on Multiple Subnet workers (Bare Metal)

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

My question is how to install kubernetes Cluster from the give below Requirement.

3 Master Nodes IP Range  10.90.10.0/24

```
Master1 :10.90.10.20 
Master2: 10.90.10.21 
Master3: 10.90.10.22
```

3 Worker Nodes  IP Range

```
Worker1: 192.168.30.20  ----->   192.168.30.0/24

Worker2: 192.168.50.11  --------------------------> 192.168.50.0/24

Worker3: 192.168.11.2   --------------------------------------------> 192.168.11.0/24
```

Which Network Plugin need to use for such Multi Subnet Cluster

1. Calico ?
2. weave ?
3. flannel ? 
   Something else

Do i need any extra Routing ?

Just wanted to tell Ping is possible on all the above Provided IPs. SSH works, Ping works.

Comment: Where are your nodes running? bare metal? cloud?

Comment: I plan to run on Bare Metal

Comment: As far as I know, the network topology of the Nodes doesn't matter to the CNI network, so long as they can reach each other and the necessary ports are open; the clusters I've run have Nodes in separate subnets without drama. I don't believe flannel is a recommended CNI provider anymore

Comment: I tested it by using Calico. the problem i get POD to POD Communication issue. example if i run MicroService application then POD distributes the load and select any worker in this case i get an issue. if POD run selected host the  complete MicroService Application then all looks good.

Comment: What do you suggest for me. which one is better Calico or Wave ? are do u have any other idea would be appreciated